# Animating Random walk

Tags: plotting, random, animation

I need to make a animation of a development of a random walk. The code for generating the walk itself works, but when I try to animate it, I get an error saying

> Non-negative machine-sized integer expected at position 3 in NestList

I guess the error is referring to the fact that in NestList, n is the value of how many times we repeat the thing and my code gets a negative value?

If I just plot it, it also works.
(I am using the DataRange function for the graph to start at 0)

Can somebody help me and tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thank you!

```
fwalk[n_] := 
  Module[{x = 0}, NestList[(x = #) + RandomChoice[{-1, 1}] &, 0, n]];
With[{g = fwalk[n]},
 Animate[
  ListLinePlot[g, DataRange -> {0, 20}],
  {n, 0, 20}, AnimationRunning -> False]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not defining `n` for the animation. And there are various problems with the animation code. Please see if this is what you want.

```
fwalk[n_] := Accumulate@RandomChoice[{-1, 1}, n];
animateWalk[step_] := 
 With[{g = fwalk[step]}, 
  Animate[ListLinePlot[Take[g, n], 
    PlotRange -> {{1, step}, MinMax[g]}], {n, 1, step, 1}, 
   AnimationRunning -> False]]
```

## Part 2

As OP required, a new auto-scaling function is added. The new function requires a new parameter: the initial plot range (i.e. the minimum plot range). The plot range doubles when the step is a power of 2, except for the last step, the graphics will expand only to the max step size instead of the next power of 2.

```
fwalk[n_] := Accumulate@RandomChoice[{-1, 1}, n];
animateWalkScale[step_, minstep_] := 
 With[{g = fwalk[step]}, 
  Animate[ListLinePlot[Take[g, n], 
    PlotRange -> {{1, Max[Min[step, 2^Ceiling[Log2[n]]], minstep]}, 
      MinMax[g]}], {n, 1, step, 1}, AnimationRunning -> False]]
```

Try `animateWalkScale[600, 50]`

Comment: Thank you, it works.  I was wondering, could one rescale the graph, when the current value of _fwalk_ would be a multiple of 2?
Let's say the x-axis would be the same, only the graph would get finer and finer. 

Something like,
 if Mod[fwalk[n],2][x] = 0 for x going from 0 to _step_ then make the shift or 'squeeze' the graph to the left by 1/2.

I was thinking of using something like this 

`if[Mod[walk[n], 2][[n]], DataRange -> [1, step/2], 
 DataRange -> [1, step]]`

and just plugging it into the function, but of course it isn't that easy. Any ideas? 
Thank you.

Comment: @Randomcloud just saw it. Please see the update of my answer.